# Reference request: monochromatic paths in edge-colored complete graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, extremal-graph-theory, ramsey-theory

Given $k,c \in \mathbb{N}$, let $P(k,c)$ be the minimum $n$ such that no matter how we color the edges of the complete graph $K_n$ with $c$ colors, there is always a monochromatic path of length $k$.

What are the best known upper and lower bounds for $P(k,c)$?

Answer (score 8):

For $c=2$, it is a theorem of [Gerencsér and Gyárfás](http://www.renyi.hu/~gyarfas/Cikkek/01_GerencserGyarfas_OnRamseyTypeProblems.pdf) that $P(k,2)=\lfloor (3k-2)/2 \rfloor$.

For $c=3$, [Gyárfás, Ruszinkó, Sárközy and Szemerédi](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~gsarkozy/Cikkek/27.pdf) proved that for sufficiently large $k$, 
$P(k,3)=2k-1$ if $k$ is odd, and $2k-2$ if $k$ is even.

The exact asymptotics are unknown for larger values of $c$ (as far as I know).

Comment: I think these results would be for paths with $k$ vertices; the question is about paths of length $k$, so $k+1$ vertices.

Comment: Yes, you are right that these results are for paths with $k$ vertices.  For this question, I conveniently regarded a path of length $k$ as a path with $k$ vertices (the notion of the length of a path is somewhat ambiguous, although I usually consider the length as the number of edges).

Answer (score 5):

For the multi-color Ramsey numbers of even cycles, [Luczak, Simonovits and Skokan](https://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jgt.20572) proved that $R(C_k;c)\le ck+o(k)$ for fixed number $c$ of colors and $k\rightarrow \infty$.

For odd cycles, [Bondy and Erdos](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0095-8956(73)80005-X) claim that $R(C_k;c)\le (c+2)!k$.

Both upper bounds apply also for paths with $k$ vertices since $P(k-1,c) \le R(C_k;c)$.